# сборка css пакета с помощью webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack4

у меня есть точка входа common_style.js, где подключается несколько vue компонентов с расширением .vue. После компиляции webpack отдаёт common_style-{hash}.css и common_style-{hash}.js

Могу я настроить webpack именно для этой точки входа так, что-бы он собирал только css пакет, при условии, что стили vue компонента будут лежать в самом компоненте?

Comment: 1) чем Вам мешает файл `common_style-{hash}.js` 2) А Сейчас стили не в компонентах  `.vue`?

Comment: @Дмытрык 1) он не мешает, но как я понимаю, на его сборку тратится какое-то время, и можно его сэкономить. 2) нет, они там

Comment: похоже, можно собрать только css bundle - правильно настроив vue-loader. в его документации описано, как обрабатывать файлы css и блоки style внутри vue компонента. Попробую

Comment: разберетесь - можете ответить на свой вопрос самостоятельно. Может кому пригодится